# Product back Stock Alert to customer through SMS

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, api, stock, alert

I need to send **SMS** (By using any SMS API) to customers when products are back in stock.

I have added my SMS API in **Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer** class under public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Observer.php file but its not sending SMS to customers. Why?

Also its only showing two customers details instead of all customers subscribed to product stock alert. Here is my code

```
 public function process()
    {
        $email = Mage::getModel('productalert/email');
        /* @var $email Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email */
        $this->_processPrice($email);
        $this->_processStock($email);
        $this->_sendErrorEmail();

        return $this;

    $customer_stock_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')->getCollection()->addStatusFilter(0)->setCustomerOrder();
    foreach ($customer_stock_alerts as $alert){
      $stock_back_product = $alert->getProductId();
      $current_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stock_back_product);
      $current_product_name = $current_product->getName();
      $customer_info = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($alert->getCustomerId());
      $customer_name = $customer_info->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
      $customer_mobile = $customer_info->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone(); 
      $message = 0;     
      $message = "Dear $customer_name, Product $current_product_name is back in Stock";
      $message=urlencode($message);
      $sendsms = "http://api.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?sender=MSGIND&route=4&mobiles=$customer_mobile&authkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&country=91&message=$message";
      file_get_contents($sendsms);     
    }
    }
```

Can anyone share what's the issue this & why SMS is not sending?

Thanks.

Comment: You must be looking for such extension but it seems in Magento 2 https://magecomp.com/magento-2-out-of-stock-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

The Magento core uses the method `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer::process()` to send email alerts. You can either rewrite this class and connect it to your SMS API, or take the functionality of this class as an inspiration to setup your own class with custom configuration settings.

Comment: Hi, Can you please let me know how to rewrite this class it to my SMS API?
Because I can't able to use this into my custom module's Observer.php. So send me the code.

Comment: Hi, I have rewrite that class in my module's observer.php and tried to connect my SMS API. But its not working. Can you please let me know how to get the customers list who needs product back in stock alerts programatically?

Comment: No, I can't. I don't know your SMS provider, and I don't know your current code. I also don't know the error - and "it's not working" is not an error description ;)

Comment: Ok. @simonthesorcerer Please check my code and updated question above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking this codebase as reference and follow it.

https://github.com/pmclain/module-twilio?files=1

Or

If you don't know how to rewrite use Magento 2 module generation tools like below to rewrite the classes. It will provide you a skeleton. Later you can change the logic accordingly.

1.http://mage2gen.com
2. http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php

Comment: Hi, For your information my Magento version is 1.9. Will your answer is compatible for 1.9 version as well?

Comment: Hi, you can try below for Magento 1.x

This is a sample module you can follow and understand 

https://github.com/kojoman/magento-twilio-integration

To rewrite Magento 1.x classes, you can try this Magento 1 module generation tool

https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: Hi, its not helped me. I know that **Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer::process()** will send emails when product back in stock. Same way I have rewrite that class in my module's observer.php and tried to connect my SMS API. But its not working. Why?

Comment: 1. There will be a way to test the SMS API. Did you test and SMS are going?
2. If SMS is going normally, then it should work with the observer.

please share or post the module code, it will help us to analyze more about the problem.

Comment: Ok. @KalyanChakravarthi  Please check my code and updated question above.